# How to preview selected video from the gallery

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to display my selected video as preview before it uploaded, just like my preview of the image is being shown in the image below [the image preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKcn3.jpg)

I am not able to display my selected video in screen as preview because of these errors.

> Result of 'VideoPlayer' initializer is unused

```
 VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
```

```
 @State var url: URL?
 var body: some View {
 if let url {
                            VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
                        }
```

**Full Code**

```
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var selectedPhoto: PhotosPickerItem?
     @State private var image: Image?
    @State var url: URL?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack{
                
                (LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white, Color.gray]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack {
                    TextField("Type Something", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                    Spacer()
                    if let url {
                                                VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: url))
                                            }
                }
                .font(.footnote)
              
                }
            .toolbar {
                           PhotosPicker(
                               selection: $selectedPhoto,
                               matching: .videos
                           ) {
                               Image(systemName: "pencil")
                           }
```

Comment: Your `VideoPlayer` shouldn't be in a `Task` -- it needs to be in the view hierarchy itself.

Comment: okay so can show me a example please @jnpdx

Comment: No, because you haven't included a [mre], so I can't run your code and provide an answer.

Comment: okay so how would you preview a video with a given reproducible example @jnpdx

Comment: I don’t provide the [mre]. That’s for you to do as the question asker. Otherwise, the most I can do is say what I’ve already outlined in the comments.

Comment: I wasn't asking for you to provide one I was asking for a general understanding on how to preview a video like a image I can't find much information on it @jnpdx

Comment: Like I said, put your VideoPlayer in the view hierarchy. For example, put it in your top-most `VStack`

Comment: I updated the code @jnpdx

Comment: Without a [mre], I can’t help any more. Sorry

Comment: I given you the avplayer code and im asking how to preview a video how can you not reproduce that code what else do you need @jnpdx

Comment: I need a _reproducible_ example. I can’t run the code you’ve provided. If you paste what you’ve provided into a blank Xcode project, you’ll see that. See the link for what that entails. Without that, my answer won’t be too usable to you — it’ll just be what I’ve already said — the VideoPlayer needs to go in the view hierarchy.

Comment: okay I fix the code @jnpdx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of your code, mixed with code from Hacking with Swift (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-let-users-import-videos-using-photospicker):

```
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

struct Movie: Transferable {
    let url: URL
    
    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        FileRepresentation(contentType: .movie) { movie in
            SentTransferredFile(movie.url)
        } importing: { received in
            let copy = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "movie.mp4")
            
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: copy.path()) {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: copy)
            }
            
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: received.file, to: copy)
            return Self.init(url: copy)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    enum LoadState {
        case unknown, loading, loaded(Movie), failed
    }
    
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var selectedItem: PhotosPickerItem?
    @State private var loadState = LoadState.unknown
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            
            (LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.white, Color.gray]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                TextField("Type Something", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                Spacer()
                switch loadState {
                case .unknown:
                    EmptyView()
                case .loading:
                    ProgressView()
                case .loaded(let movie):
                    VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: movie.url))
                        .scaledToFit()
                case .failed:
                    Text("Import failed")
                }
            }
            .font(.footnote)
            
        }
        .toolbar {
            PhotosPicker(
                selection: $selectedItem,
                matching: .videos
            ) {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: selectedItem) { _ in
            Task {
                do {
                    loadState = .loading
                    
                    if let movie = try await selectedItem?.loadTransferable(type: Movie.self) {
                        loadState = .loaded(movie)
                    } else {
                        loadState = .failed
                    }
                } catch {
                    loadState = .failed
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In your current code, you never set `url`, so there's nothing to load. Note that in this example, a `FileRepresentation` is used to load the video, and then the `VideoPlayer` is displayed once it is loaded.